# Theory behind Regression in caffe

Tags: math, machine-learning, regression, caffe

Does anyone know the theory behind regression in Caffe? I understand that we have a loss function, but what is this applied to?

By that I mean that for the Softmax with Loss layer, we have a Softmax function and we apply cross-entropy loss to determine our updates. What I am looking for is the "Softmax function" to my Euclidean Loss. Any tips? I have looked at the Caffe layer explanation, but there it is just stated that the sum of squared errors is used as a loss function.

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it is really hard to understand the actual problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Caffe, this is rather a general regression problem.

Loss function, usually in the form of L(prediction, truth) is a function assigning a **scalar** (number) which you try to minimise in order to solve the task (which is making predictions which reassemble the true values).

In general in regression you make your predictions according to some function f(x|theta) where theta is set of parameters of your function, for example these might be set of weights of a neural network, or coefficients of a linear model. Thus your optimisation problem is

```
minimise_theta    L(f(X|theta), truth)
```

for example for L2 loss (Euclidean distance) you get

```
minimise_theta    SUM_i || f(x_i|theta) - truth_i ||^2
                           ------------   -------
                                |            |
                                v            V
                           prediction      true
                           for point      value for
                           x_i            point x_i
```

and the way you look for the best theta depends on the optimiser used, it might differentiate this function to look for minimum, you might use some metaoptimisers (like genetic methods etc.).

In particular for Caffe and neural nets, f(x_i|theta) is your neural network, which can be composed of multiple modules (layers, nodes), performing different operations according to theta and x_i. Softmax in particular does not have any parameters, thus it is not trainable, it only normalises your predictions, but you do have some trainable modules below softmax usually (such as linear layer), which are adjusted according to the above optimisation problem. You search for such parameters that your loss on the training set is minimised.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. I now see where I made my thinking mistake. I approached the Softmax function wrong. Thanks for the reply!